# Find votes by current user on a post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm building an application where users can submit posts and vote on them.

I need to find a way to allow users to delete their vote.

I started a private method called `correct_user` under my `votes_controller`, but I don't quite know how to pull the current user's vote id to a specific post. I figure once I have the ID I can pass it through to an instance variable where I can call the `vote_path(@vote), method: :delete` on it.

However, right now I don't quite know how to pull the proper id for a vote by a specific user on a specific post.

I did `@vote = current_user.votes.find_by_id(params[:id])` in my `current user` method, but obviously that's not working. Not really sure how to pull this off. Any help would be great.

votes_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :correct_user, only: [:destroy]

def destroy
  @vote.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "Your vote has been deleted"
  redirect_to root_path
end

private

def vote_params
  params.require(:vote).permit(:user_id, :post_id, :up)
end

def correct_user
  @vote = current_user.votes.find_by_id(vote_params[:post_id)
  redirect_to root_path if @vote.nil?
end
```

and from my views:

```
<%= link_to "delete", vote_path(@vote), method: :delete %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up putting this in my delete link:

`vote_path(link.votes.where(user_id: current_user).first)`

I will have to refactor and clean this up a bit, but that's what answered this question.